# functional error when trying to bind function with an object reference

Tags: c++11

Here is my code:

```
void funct(carl& c){
    std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    carl c;
    auto f = std::bind(funct,&c);
    std::packaged_task<void()> task1( f );   // error

    //std::packaged_task<void()> task1( std::bind(funct,carl()) ); this one worked though

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to bind a function and use `carl c` as parameter(& to reference). Somehow i am getting functional error when i try to complile. (Carl is just an empty class for the sake of testing).

`[error] no type named 'type' in class std::result_of...`

Though, it works if ill have to use `carl()` but i want to use an existing instance of `carl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your function expects a reference to an object, and you are passing a pointer. The correct way to bind is

```cpp
auto f = std::bind(funct,c);
```

UPDATE: actually, even more correct way to do that is

```cpp
auto f = std::bind(funct,std::ref(c));
```

Comment: I get an error when i do that too though. The error that i get is in packaged_task.

Comment: I just did it and it compiled fine. Paste the new code and the error message.

Comment: Also, see the update. Depending on the actual implementation of your `carl` class my first solution might actually not compile